# Display pdf on Html Webpage

Tags: html, jquery, css, bootstrap-4

I have my created resume via latex and i want to show my pdf as we show put image as background in webpage. I want this so that my hyperlinks in resume must work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code -

> => Replace **filename.pdf** with your **.pdf** file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>PDF View</title>
    <style>
        body{
            margin: 0;
            overflow: hidden;
        }

        iframe{
            width: 100vw;
            height: 100vh;
            border: none;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <iframe src="filename.pdf#toolbar=0&zoom=100%"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```